# Docker: not reading file

Tags: python, docker, cmd, dockerfile

I'm building a simple app using: `Dockerfile`, `app.py` and `requirements.txt`. When the Dockerfile builds I get the error: "No such file or directory". However, when I change the ADD to COPY in the Dockerfile it works. Do you know why this is?

I'm using the tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-a-dockerfile

[image: error]
[image: error fixed]

App.py

```
    from flask import Flask
    from redis import Redis, RedisError
    import os
    import socket

    # Connect to Redis
    redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        try:
            visits = redis.incr("counter")
        except RedisError:
            visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

        html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
               "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
               "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
        return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

---

requirements.txt

```
Flask
Redis
```

---

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Can you show logs of both build?

Comment: Copied your Dockerfile, and and tried to build, everything is ok, your `requirements.txt` along with `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 1):

In the first run, your working directory is `/app` inside container, and you copy contents to `/tmp`. To correct  this behavior, you should be copying contents to `/app` and it will work fine.

Second one, where you are using `add` is correct since you are adding contents to `/app`., and not `/tmp`